# How to finetune an LLM model on your own codebase?

Tags: code-generation, huggingface, large-language-model

I have 10 code repositories in Javascript (VueJS) (Each repository corresponds to 1 Theme)

I want to train an LLM model on these 10 code repositories so that I can generate new themes using prompts.

The LLM model take the context of 10 code repositories as reference (since the file structure is similar for all repositories)

I'm a complete beginner with LLMs and ML.

How to finetune an LLM model on my own codebase ?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow, since it is a general problem, without a specific programming solution. It is better suited to the AI or Data Science StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can actually do is create a custom prompt and pass in one or two examples such that the llm learns from one shot or few shot. Later in the custom prompt you can pass in the paramters on which you want the llm to take decision and give you the output. For such tasks I feel OpenAI models like GPT-3 and other's work well.

Hope it answer's your question:)